# How to disable conversion of Vue component properties to special characters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a string containing the character " " (non-breaking space).

I pass the string to the component like this:

```
<name-component test='Paper black'></name-component>
```

The component name-component in the property `test` = `Paper&nbsp;black`.

How to get the string 'Paper black' in its original form?

Comment: @Antonio I can, but in this case, we need an unbreakable gap. So comes from the database and would not like to process the issue, because the user must be sure that he entered it is an unbroken space.
And you need to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a problem with in-DOM templates. If you use single-file components or strings to define your templates then this won't happen.

When you pass `el: '#app'` or equivalent to Vue it grabs the template from inside the element using `innerHTML`. See:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/9fbd416635eb3d7b32cd73b7c29f8377003c4dc8/src/platforms/web/entry-runtime-with-compiler.js#L14

The `innerHTML` value returned by the browser contains `&nbsp;` instead of a non-breaking space character.

The example code below illustrates a few different cases and what happens. The key thing to notice is that the problem only occurs when the non-breaking space is included directly inside the template in the HTML. I have included various bits of console logging to illustrate what is going on and to confirm that the spaces really are non-breaking space (character `190` in decimal, `a0` in hex).

```js
const NameComponent = {
  template: `<div>{{ test }}</div>`,
  props: ['test'],
  
  mounted () {
    console.log('In mounted:')
    console.log(this.test)
    console.log(this.test.charCodeAt(5))
  }
}

// This component uses a string template,
// not an in-DOM template. All is well.
const WrappedComponent = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <name-component test="Paper black"/>
    </div>
  `,
  
  components: {
    NameComponent
  }
}

// This shows the value of `innerHTML`
// that Vue sees for the template.
console.log(document.getElementById('app').innerHTML)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    NameComponent,
    WrappedComponent
  },
  
  data () {
    return {
      test: 'Paper black'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <name-component :test="test"></name-component>
  <name-component test="Paper black"></name-component>
  <wrapped-component></wrapped-component>
</div>
```

Of course it could be argued that the correct way for Vue's template parser to interpret `test="Paper&nbsp;black"` would be to treat the `&nbsp;` as a non-breaking space character. To my mind it should. However, it does not. Only a small subset of HTML entities are decode correctly:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/9fbd416635eb3d7b32cd73b7c29f8377003c4dc8/src/compiler/parser/html-parser.js#L42

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a very cool answer. I'll try soon!

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes:
<template>
  <div v-html="test"></div>
<template>

No:
<template>
  <div>
    {{ test }}
  </div>
<template>
```

Comment: It works that way, of course. But the fact is that the user can specify such text: "Paper black <div>". And if you output as html, the space will be displayed and there will be another element div (which is not necessary). And if to deduce as the text, instead of a continuous space will deduce &nbsp;, but correctly will deduce <div> (the usual text).

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace with non-break space code `\xa0`.

```
<div id="app">
  <my-component name="custom   space"></my-component>
</div>
-----------------------
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: `
    <div>
      {{ nameWithSpaces }}
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    nameWithSpaces() {
      return this.name.replace(/ /g, '\xa0');
    }
  }
})
```

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/minion/pen/JjoKqaL).